# Quick way to turn object into single-element list?

Tags: c#, list, .net-2.0

What is the quickest in `C# 2.0` to create a one-element list out of a single object?

eg:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject> { obj };    // is this possible?
```

Comment: Is that a joke? It is as easy as havingt a static variable. Assign to variable in static contructor, finished.

Comment: @JefferyKhan I suspect the question uses "singleton" to mean "list containing one element".  CJ7, is that true?

Comment: no ..google what a singleton is in .NET look up MUTEX as well.. singleton meaning single Instance..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I know what singleton is *supposed* to mean, in terms of the singleton pattern, but I suspect that this is not what CJ7 is asking about.

Comment: What purpose could a list with a single member possibly serve?  At least what more than stopping at `MyObject obj = new MyObject();`?

Comment: That wasn't meant for you phoog it was meant for CJ7

Comment: @JefferyKhan A list with a single member is very useful when you want to use some code that operates on a List, but you only have one object to put in that list.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I see -- the "no" at the beginning of the comment threw me off.

Comment: not a problem +1 for your great example as well..

Comment: @JefferyKhan: I have to pass the object to a function that only takes a list of the object as a parameter.

Answer (score 8):

Your sample code

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject> { obj };
```

uses a collection initializer, which was not available in C# 2.0.  You could use an array initializer, instead:

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>(new MyObject[] { obj });
```

Or, just make the list and add the object:

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>(1);
list.Add(obj);
```

Note that "singleton" usually refers to the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern); as you see from the comments, it's confusing to use that term to refer to a collection containing one element.

Comment: Not a problem.. Jon is a very good in regards to proving awesome .NET tutorials and knowledge

Answer (score 3):

You could create the following extension and just call it on any object you want to create a list of itself.

The only down side is that it would pollute the extension space...   So I would only do this if you found yourself using it often.

```
public static partial class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> ToListOfSelf<T>(this T item)
    {
        return new List<T>() { item };
    }
}
```

e.g. myObject.ToListOfSelf();