# How can a list with one member be useful?

Tags: c#, .net, generic-collections

I read an SO which asked for the easiest way to create a list with a one member.

[Quick way to turn object into single-element list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998343/quick-way-to-turn-object-into-singleton-list)

This raised a question for me, when would this be useful?

I can't think of an example when I would use a `List<T>` with a single member over just the `T` variable itself.

Can someone explain or provide an example?

Comment: Apparently the list might be modified later. As [phoog explains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13998400/11683), the term "singleton" is used by the OP erroneously.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the singleton pattern. I am simply looking for examples or reasons why one would want to use a `List<T>` with a single member.

Comment: Also, a single object, say a property, can be modified arguably easier than the single member of a list.

Comment: @JefferyKhan but you might be implementing an interface whose design you do not control, i.e., from another library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this happens when you have a logical collection of elements that just happens to contain one member.  For example, you might have a House class with a collection of Room items, but the OneRoomSchoolhouse class only has one object in its Rooms collection.

As another example, you might have a method with this signature:

```
void LogNewItems(List<Item> newItems);
```

If you have only one item, you would have to pass it thus:

```
LogNewItems(new List<Item> { item });
```

In fact, if you're designing the item-logging API, you might create a convenience method so developers don't have to do that.  The method could look something like this:

```
void LogNewItem(Item item)
{
    LogNewItems(new List<Item> { item });
}
```

Comment: This makes sense and is pretty much what I was looking for.  Good example.  Thanks.

Comment: @JefferyKhan you're welcome.  I also added a more general answer and another example at the top of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You may have to implement an interface that requires returning a collection of objects. You may sometimes wish to return a single object but you still have to fulfil the interface and one way to do this is to create a list containing a single object and then return the list.

```
class ConstantValue : IValueProvider
{
    public override IList<int> getValues()
    {
         return new List<int> { 1 };
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. 0, 1, somtimes 2 items in a collection are very common cases of a collection. If possible in real usage consider using IEnumerable instead of List, than you can use `Enumerable.Empty` and `Enumerable.Repeat` to represent 0 and 1 items correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have to have `DoSomethingWithAListOfFoo(List<Foo> items)` AND a `DoSomethingWithAFoo(Foo item)` implementation.  `DoSomethingWithAFoo` can simply create a single item list and pass it to `DoSomethingWithAListOfFoo`.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no overload `IEnumerable<T> Except(T)` available already.